# Is there an equivelent to instruments for someone that doesn't want to compile their app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

I don't want to compile my app every-time I want to test it in instruments is there any other program or way of utilizing this benefit without having to compile every-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool that is much easier to use than the Instruments.  The tool is the Clang Static Analyzer.  The [website describes](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) how to install and use the tool set.  It is so easy to use and very efficient.  I use it all the time.

The commands are:

```
xcodebuild clean
scan-build -k -V xcodebuild
```

It is really easy to use as the results come up in the web browser!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just saw you post this on my other question and btw I asked this before I saw your post